# How to share multiple items or a folder using ShareLink

Tags: swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI's `ShareLink` to share JSON files but I'd like to share multiple files at once. Preferably creating a folder and sharing the whole folder, since I'd like to add `Image`s as well.

How would I go about this? I already created a custom struct that conforms to `Transferable` to create and share JSON files. I've tried creating an extension to `Array` that conforms to `Transferable` but I couldn't make it work.

### Update

I've managed to utilise the `ShareLink` initialiser that takes multiple items. This only works for `URL` or `Data` items, not for every object that conforms to `Transferable`.

To clarify, this is my custom object that I use to share a JSON file with:

```swift
struct JSONFile {
    let url: URL
}

extension JSONFile: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .json) { jsonFile in
            SentTransferredFile(jsonFile.url)
        }
    }
}
```

I save serialised JSON data to a `URL` and create an instance of `JSONFile` with it. Now I can share the `JSONFile` with `ShareLink` like this:

```swift
ShareLink(
    "Share title",
    item: jsonFile,
    preview: SharePreview("title.json")
)
```

When I want to share multiple items I can do:

```swift
ShareLink(
    "Share title",
    items: [jsonFile1.url, jsonFile2.url]
)
```

This works, but it seems weird to create an object that conforms to `Transferable` first and then only using its url.

Also, this exports multiple items, but I'd still like to export them in one folder.